# checking sorting button using Cypress in Saucedemo.com

Tags: cypress

I was practicing UI Testing using Cypress in website [saucedemo.com](https://www.saucedemo.com/index.html) which is demo e-commerce website. I tried to test the sorting selection button. it works just fine for the standard_user account but for the problem_user account, the sorting won't work in any cases(There'are a-z sorting, z-a sorting, Price low to high sorting and price high to low sorting) but my code passes for those two cases so i was wondering if i code it correctly? and this is my code

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkAtoZsorting", () =>{
    cy.get('[ class="product_sort_container"]')
        .select('az')
        .should("have.value","az")
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').should(($item1) => {
            expect($item1).to.have.length(6)
        });
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(0).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Backpack");
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(1).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bike Light");
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(2).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bolt T-Shirt");
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(3).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket");
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(4).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Onesie");
        cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(5).should("have.text","Test.allTheThings() T-Shirt (Red)");
});
 Cypress.Commands.add("checkZtoAsorting", () =>{
cy.get('[ class="product_sort_container"]')
    .select('za')
    .should("have.value","za")
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').should(($item1) => {
        expect($item1).to.have.length(6) 
    });
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(0).should("have.text","Test.allTheThings() T-Shirt (Red)");
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(1).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Onesie");
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(2).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket");
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(3).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bolt T-Shirt");
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(4).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bike Light");
    cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(5).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Backpack");
```

Really need help ....

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it worked for me using **standard_user** and **problem_user**.

commands.js (unchanged):

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkAtoZsorting", () =>{
  cy.get('[ class="product_sort_container"]')
    .select('az')
    .should("have.value","az")
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').should(($item1) => {
    expect($item1).to.have.length(6)
  });
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(0).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Backpack");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(1).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bike Light");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(2).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Bolt T-Shirt");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(3).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(4).should("have.text","Sauce Labs Onesie");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(5).should("have.text","Test.allTheThings() T-Shirt (Red)");
});

Cypress.Commands.add("checkZtoAsorting", () => {
  cy.get('[ class="product_sort_container"]')
    .select('za')
    .should("have.value", "za")
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').should(($item1) => {
    expect($item1).to.have.length(6)
  });
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(0).should("have.text", "Test.allTheThings() T-Shirt (Red)");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(1).should("have.text", "Sauce Labs Onesie");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(2).should("have.text", "Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(3).should("have.text", "Sauce Labs Bolt T-Shirt");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(4).should("have.text", "Sauce Labs Bike Light");
  cy.get('[class="inventory_item_name"]').eq(5).should("have.text", "Sauce Labs Backpack");
});
```

spec.js:

```
describe('sort', () => {

  it('sort standard_user', () => {

    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('input#user-name').type('standard_user');
    cy.get('input#password').type('secret_sauce');
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();

    cy.checkAtoZsorting();
    cy.checkZtoAsorting();


  });

  it('sort problem_user', () => {

    cy.visit('/');
    cy.get('input#user-name').type('problem_user');
    cy.get('input#password').type('secret_sauce');
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();

    cy.checkAtoZsorting();
    cy.checkZtoAsorting();


  });

});
```

[image: Results]

Remark: You can use this format when using `cy.get()` with class attribute:

```
cy.get('.product_sort_container')
```